# How to save file in C# on RichTextBox with keyboard shorcut

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing the code editor in C# and i want to make the saving with keyboard shorcut CTRL + S this is my saving file code

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var di = new SaveFileDialog();
    di.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
    di.FileName = "Txt" + ".txt";
    var result = di.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(di.FileName, textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

I want the tip how to solve it or piece of code that will work.

Comment: Go to the designer, select your button, and look for the ShortcutKeys in the Properties window.

Comment: i have only ShortcutsEnabled True

Comment: I'm talking about the `saveToolStripMenuItem1` object.

Comment: and how can i make it save the file when i am in it and not ask for space

Comment: `when i am in it and not ask for space`  I don't know what that means.  A RichTextBox has a `SaveFile` method.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Save menu strip item:

[image: Menustripitem selected]

Open the properties window and set the keyboard shortcut:

[image: Setting keyboard shortcut in properties]

Note that your code is only saving the rich text (rich = formatted) as plain text, so your file will not have that formatting. If you want to save as rich text, use

```cs
richTextBox1.SaveFile("whatever.rtf");
```